# Kotlin Multiplatform: Project Structure, Displaying Images and implementing Android SharedPreferences

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm new to Android development, and this is my first time working on a Koltin multiplatform project.

My project structure is given below-

```
project-root
├── android
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── java
│   │       │   └── org.example.application
│   │       │       └── MainActivity.kt (only being used to set app name and icon, invoking Application.kt inside setContent)
│   │       ├── res
│   │       │   ├── drawable
│   │       │   │   └── icon.png
│   │       │   ├── values
│   │       │   └── strings.xml (contains app name)
│   │       └── AndroidManifest.xml
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── common
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── androidMain
│   │   │   ├── kotlin
│   │   │   │   └── org.example.application
│   │   │   │       └── common
│   │   │   │           └── Platform.kt (for actual functions)
│   │   │   └── AndroidManifest.xml
│   │   ├── commonMain
│   │   │   ├── kotlin
│   │   │   │   └── org.example.application
│   │   │   │       └── common
│   │   │   │           └── Platform.kt (for expect functions)
│   │   │   └── resources (marked as resources root)
│   │   │       └── drawable (contains images to be displayed in app)
│   │   │           ├── a.png
│   │   │           ├── b.png
│   │   │           └── c.png
│   │   ├── desktopMain
│   │   │   └── kotlin
│   │   │       └── org.example.application
│   │   │           └── common
│   │   │               └── Platform.kt (for actual functions)
│   │   └── jvmAndAndroidMain
│   │       └── kotlin
│   │           └── org.example.application
│   │               └── view
│   │                   └── Application.kt (contains composable functions to be displayed in app)
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── desktop
│   ├── src
│   │   └── jvmMain
│   │       ├── kotlin
│   │       │   └── org.example.application
│   │       │       └── Main.kt (only being used to set app name and icon, invoking Application.kt inside Window)
│   │       └── resources
│   │           └── icon.png
│   └── build.gradle.kts
└── build.gradle.kts
```

Now I'm facing the following problems-

1. First and foremost, I'm not sure if my project structure is correct. I've referred to an example project by JetBrains as there were no tutorials available. So, can someone please tell me if I need to restructure it.
2. I'm using compose UI toolkit for developing frontend for android as well as desktop. Now, I want to display some images in the app which are located inside **common/src/commonMain/resources/drawable**. When I use `Image(painter = painterResource("drawable/${imgName}.png"))` where, `imgName` is a variable containing the image name (a/b/c) inside **common/src/jvmAndAndroidMain/kotlin/org.example.application/view/Application.kt** . It works fine when I run the desktop application but on android it gives an error insisting me to use resource id instead of resource path.
3. I need to use app data so while writing platform specific code for Android inside **common/src/androidMain/kotlin/org.example.application/Platform.kt** when I try to implement SharedPreferences using this-
   `val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`, it is asking for a context.

What I've tried till now-

For Problem **#2**

Even when I try to use `Image(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.imgName)` it is unable to locate the images.

For Problem **#3**

I tried to declare a companion object inside MainActivity class located at **android/src/main/java/org.example.application/MainActivity.kt** like this-

```
init {
        instance = this
    }

companion object {
    private var instance: MainActivity? = null

    fun applicationContext() : Context {
        return instance!!.applicationContext
    }
}
```

But when I try to import MainActivity in **common/src/androidMain/kotlin/org.example.application/common/Platform.kt**, it gives a circular import error.

Thank you for your time. Any help would be appreciated :)